# In extjs how to get radio buttons value?

Tags: extjs, radio-button

I am creating project of multiple choice question paper in extjs and yii framework. My server side design is in yii framework while client side is in extjs. In extjs i have view as-

```
Question.js=
            Ext.define('Balaee.view.question.Question', 
             {
        extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
        requires:[
                  'Balaee.view.question.QuestionView'
                  ],
        id:'QuestionId',
        alias:'widget.question',
        title:'Question',
        height:180,
        items:[
            {
                xtype:'questionView',
            },

        ],//end of items square
        buttons:[
              {
                  xtype:'button',
                  fieldLabel:'Submit',
                  name:'answer',
                  formBind:true,
                  text:'submit',
                  action:'submitAction',
              }
        ]
                 });


QuestionView.js=
            Ext.define('Balaee.view.question.QuestionView',
            {
        extend:'Ext.view.View',
        id:'QuestionViewId',
        alias:'widget.questionView',
        store:'Question',
        config:
        {
            tpl:'<tpl for=".">'+
                '<div id="main">'+
                '</br>'+
                '<b>Question :-</b> {question}</br>'+
                '<p>-------------------------------------------</p>'+

                '<tpl for="options">'+     // interrogate the kids property  within the data
                    //'<p>&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="opt"    >&nbsp{option}</p>'+
                 '<p>&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio"    name="opt{questionNumber}" >&nbsp{option} </p>'+
                '</tpl></p>'+

                '</div>'+
                '</tpl>',
            itemSelector:'div.main',    
        }
              });
```

So i am displaying 30 questions and its optopns as radio buttons in extjs. These questions are get retrieved from client side. 
On click of submit button i want to get all user's selected radio button's value. So how to get selected radio buttons value?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do something this complicated? Take a look at forms and form fields instead.